# Morita Equivalence of Full Corners in $C^*$-algebras

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a $C^*$-algebra with a unique normalized trace and $p \in \mathcal{A}$ is a projection so that $\mathcal{B} = p\mathcal{A}p$ is a full corner.

1. Does $\mathcal{B}$ have a unique normalized trace so that for $a \in \mathcal{A}, tr_{\mathcal{B}}(pap) = \frac{tr_{\mathcal{A}}(a)}{tr_{\mathcal{A}}(p)}\,?$
2. I have read that $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are Morita equivalent. Maybe this is obvious, but is there an easy way to describe the isomorphism $K_0(\mathcal{A}) \cong K_0(\mathcal{B})$ using the projection $p\,?$

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to (2) is yes, as $X=pA$ is an imprimitivity bimodule between $B$ and $A$. So if $E$ is a (left) projective finite type module over $A$, then $X\otimes_A E$ is projective finite type over $B$.

Comment: Thanks Alain - suppose I'm given a projection in $\mathcal{A}$ or in $M_n(\mathcal{A}).$ Based on this method, is it easy to construct a projection in $M_k(\mathcal{B})$ that it gets mapped to under this isomorphism?